# I am trying to add files to google drive using kotlin in cororutines but getting error that main thread will be blocked even if i am using coroutine

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-drive-android-api

Here is the issue
I am making the file and then adding to google drive but it says inappropriate blocking method call.
[image]

Comment: Please update your existing question instead of opening new ones on the same topic. Also, please don't post pictures of code ([see here for why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question))

Comment: It sure looks like `create` blocks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run long running task in another [Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) or use [Coroutine](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-overview.html) to execute blocking method.

by using Coroutine it will be sth like this:

```
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        launch{
          mfile.execute();
        }
    }
```